# How to do a double translation of a large text file using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, google-translate

I have a `text.csv` file of size 2 x 400000 that look like this:

```
         col 1         col2
0        text          text
1        text          text
2        text          text
...
399999   text          text
400000   text          text
```

Each column needs to be translated from English to French and then back to English again. I tried doing this manually with Google Translate but my file is 60MB in size and Google Translate only supports files upto 1 MB.

Can this Eng > Fr > Eng translation somehow be done automatically using Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following to read a csv file and both columns are translated from English to french and back to English for every row within the file:

```
import csv
from google.cloud import translate
translate_client = translate.Client()
def translateFunction(text,target):
        translation = translate_client.translate(text,target_language=target)
        return (translation['translatedText'])
output_file = open('output.csv', 'wb')
reader = csv.reader(open('source.csv', 'rU'), dialect=csv.excel_tab,delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    column1=translateFunction(translateFunction(row[1],'fr'),'en')
    column2=translateFunction(translateFunction(row[2],'fr'),'en')
    output_text = ','.join([row[0],column1,column2])
    output_file.write(output_text.encode('utf-8')+'\n')
output_file.close()
```

Keep in mind this does several requests to the Translation API.